# How do I refresh an page automatically every time an net::(ANY ERROR) is detected on the inspect console on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, javascript, code, protocol

So I have an question. The most annoying error I have in Chrome is the net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, which occurs for broken images. I used Codepal to help me make this script, but it does not work. I also used AI Javascript creator alternitaves, like ZZZ Code, but it does not work. So any JavaScript code that helps? Thanks!